# Is there a way to disable column sorting in HeidiSQL?

Tags: heidisql

After running a query that returns results in HeidiSQL, the results pane will display the query results. If you click on one of the column headers, it will sort the results by that column.

I ran a query that took a while to complete and after the results were finally displayed, I accidentally clicked on one of these column headers, and now the HeidiSQL client is not responding because it's currently trying to sort the large dataset.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can click a table in the left database tree, so you have the "*Table: xyz*" tab activated on the right. Then rightclick the table in the tree, and click "*Clear data tab filter*":[image: table rightclick menu]

To disable sorting and filtering permanently for all tables, go to Tools > Preferences > Data editors, and uncheck "*Remember filters...*": [image]

Comment: Why downvoting? The answer was as clear and precise as the question. Simple enough.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the feature for all datasets by default, not just specific tables? It's pretty frustrating to click by error on the title label of a query that took 2 seconds to run and pay for it with 10 minutes of waiting time if you're lucky enough for it not to crash.